# Using Intellij with Spring-Data-Neo4j /w Aspectj gives Java error when trying to create the Repos

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, neo4j, spring-data

I am working in Intellij v13 writing Spring-Data (with AspectJ + Neo4j). If I have the below Service file:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class BaseClassRepositoryImpl implements BaseClassRepository{
}

public interface BaseClassRepository extends BaseClassRepositoryCustom, GraphRepository<BaseClass> {

}
```

Using the [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-graph-examples/tree/master/hello-worlds/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/hellograph), the code above should work. However, Intellij is giving me an exception:

```
java: local.ffxiv.repos.BaseClassRepositoryImpl is not abstract and does not override     abstract method findByName(java.lang.String) in local.ffxiv.repos.BaseClassRepository
```

I searched everywhere trying to figure out why Intellij is doing this. Anyone else seeing this?

Here's the build.gradle script as well:

```
project.ext {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    targetCompatibility = "1.6"
    springDataGraphVersion = "2.3.0.RC1"
    springVersion = "4.0.0.RELEASE"
    junitVersion = "4.11"
    neo4jVersion = "2.0.0"
    aspectjVersion = "1.7"
}
apply from: 'http://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/raw/master/build/gradle/springdataneo4j.gradle'

configurations {
    runtime
    testCompile
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M7")
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'ffxiv_db'
    version = '0.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "http://m2.neo4j.org" }
}

dependencies {

    // compile list
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:0.5.0.M7"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:$springDataGraphVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-aspects:$springDataGraphVersion"
    compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:$neo4jVersion"
    compile "javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:$springVersion"

    // Test dependencies
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:$neo4jVersion:tests"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

[image: IntelliJ Screenshot of pop-up message]

Here's it's asking me to implement exists(Long) which I shouldn't need to do but IntelliJ keeps tell me. If I do Alt+Enter, on the popup message, I can hit "Implement Methods" and it creates a whole bunch of overrides with null return values. However, according to the docs, it should infer what I want to do by the name of the function and derive what the function does for simple CRUD operations. I.E. for 'findByName' should return a property named "Name" and it creates the proper function.

Comment: where is your `findByName` declared?

Comment: I think the example you used is outdated, please check the appropriate code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples

Comment: @MichaelHunger Do you know where a build.gradle would be that's updated using aspectj? The one referenced in "Good Relationships" is out-dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear: the `local.ffxiv.repos.BaseClassRepositoryImpl` class should be declared as abstract or has to implement the `findByName(java.lang.String)` method of the `local.ffxiv.repos.BaseClassRepository` (which extends the `BaseClassRepositoryCustom` where as I guess the `findByName` is declared).

Compare with the example you refer: `WorldRepositoryImpl` implements `MyWorldRepository` and overrides all of its methods.

**UPD**

And probably your `BaseClassRepositoryImpl` should implement the `BaseClassRepositoryCustom` instead of the `BaseClassRepository`. Then you will have to override only methods of the `BaseClassRepositoryCustom` but not the whole `GraphRepository`

Comment: Well, that I get. I'll post up a screenshot of it. IntellJ wants me to  implement like 20 methods that I don't need to do (according to how Spring/AspectJ) works.

Comment: Added screenshot above and more info. Also please not that my interface "BaseClassRepository" has no functions itself.

Comment: Dam, @Eugene, how the heck did I not notice the relationship. Yeah, I was doing the wrong one. Thanks for the direction.